# Reading a text file to a doubly linked list and outputting it - C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, pointers, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to read in a file and use a doubly linked list to store the data and output the stored data. But whenever I run my program, it outputs nothing and terminates. I have no errors compiling the code.

Header file with the pre-processor directives and the structs

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

typedef struct sentry  sentry;

struct stud
{
   string term;
   string title;
   string description;
   string tktNum;
   string location;
   string lecDay;
   string instructor;
   string labLoc;
   string labDay;
   string labInstruct;
   string units;
   string preReqs;
   string grade;
};
struct slist
{
    int length;
    sentry *first;
    sentry *last;
};
struct sentry
{
    slist *list;
    sentry *next;
    sentry *prev;
    stud *data;
};

void readFile(slist *&header);
```

My main.cpp
It calls the read file function and outputs it

```
#include "header.h"

int main()
{
    slist *header = NULL;

    sentry *temp, *node;
    temp = header->first;

    readFile(header);

    for(int i=0; i<header->length; ++i)
    {
        cout << node->data->term << endl;
        cout << node->data->title << endl;
        cout << node->data->description << endl;
        cout << node->data->tktNum << endl;
        cout << node->data->location << endl;
        cout << node->data->lecDay << endl;
        cout << node->data->instructor << endl;
        cout << node->data->labLoc << endl;
        cout << node->data->labInstruct << endl;
        cout << node->data->units << endl;
        cout << node->data->preReqs << endl;
        cout << node->data->grade << endl;

        node-> prev = header-> last;
        node-> next = NULL;
        temp = header -> last;
        temp-> next = node;
        header-> last = node;
        node = temp->prev;
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

My readFile function - it reads in from a text file and stores the data into the linked list

```
#include "header.h"

void readFile(slist *&header)
{
    ifstream fin;
    sentry *node, *temp;

    fin.open("data.txt");
    while(!fin.eof())
    {
        if(header == NULL)
        {
            header = new slist;
            header-> length = 0;
            header-> first = NULL;
            header-> last  = NULL;

            node = new sentry;
            header-> first = node;
            header-> last  = node;
            node-> prev = NULL;
            node-> next = NULL;
         }else
        {
            node = new sentry;
            node-> prev = header-> last;
            node-> next = NULL;
            temp = header -> last;
            temp-> next = node;
            header-> last = node;
        }
        node->data = new stud;
        getline(fin, node->data->term);
        getline(fin, node->data->title);
        getline(fin, node->data->description);
        getline(fin, node->data->tktNum);
        getline(fin, node->data->location);
        getline(fin, node->data->lecDay);
        getline(fin, node->data->instructor);
        getline(fin, node->data->labLoc);
        getline(fin, node->data->labDay);
        getline(fin, node->data->labInstruct);
        getline(fin, node->data->units);
        getline(fin, node->data->preReqs);
        getline(fin, node->data->grade);
        header->length++;
    }
}
```

My data.txt file (the text file that is used to read data from)

```
Fall 2222
CS101
Computer Science Intro
12345
SCI546
MWF 1230PM
John Doe
SCI547
MWF 230PM
John Doe
4
N/A
B

Spring 111
English 101
Intro to English
6789
LI123
TTH 130PM
Jane Doe
N/A
N/A
N/A
N/A
3
N/A
A
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
slist *header = NULL;
```

You never allocate anything for `header`. `header` is always `NULL`. Also it's better to call it `list`, not `header`. You need instead:

```
slist list;
```

You have other uninitialized pointer, example `sentry *node;` You cannot use this unless it is pointing to something.

You are using C-style declaration in some parts, sort of. C-type structures can be as follows:

```
typedef struct sentry_t sentry; //in C
```

In C++ you can simply write `struct sentry;`

But you don't actually need this. You need the following structures instead:

```
struct stud
{
    ... as before
};

struct snode
{
    stud data;
    snode *next;
    snode *prev;
};

struct slist
{
    int length;
    snode *head;
    snode *tail;
};
```

`slist` is doubly linked list and `snode` are its nodes.

Note that I changed the structures, now `stud` is contained within `snode`, so you don't need to make a separate allocation with `new` (in a practical application you have to free all the memory, you want to avoid unnecessary allocations)

Now you can declare and initialize your list:

```
int main()
{
    //declare and initialize the list
    slist list;
    list.head = NULL;
    list.tail = NULL;
    list.length = 0;

    readFile(list);

    snode *node = list.head;
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    {
        cout << node->data.term << endl;
        cout << node->data.title << endl;
        cout << node->data.description << endl;
        ...
        node = node->next;
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The read function should be as follows:

```
void readFile(slist &list)
{
    ifstream fin("file");
    while(fin.good())
    {
        snode *node = new snode;
        if(list.head == NULL)
        {
            node->prev = NULL;
            node->next = NULL;
            list.head = node;
            list.tail = node;
        }
        else
        {
            list.tail->next = node;
            node->prev = list.head;
            node->next = NULL;
            list.tail = node;
        }

        getline(fin, node->data.term);
        getline(fin, node->data.title);
        getline(fin, node->data.description);
        ...
        getline(fin, node->data.grade);
        list.length++;

        string blankline;
        if(!getline(fin, blankline))
            break;
    }
}
```

Use `fin.good()` instead of `!fin.eof()`. Note that you have a blank line in your file. You want to skip that or break the loop when it reaches the last line.

Comment: thanks for answering, i'm getting an error for the line of code "node = node->next;" in main. The error says that assigning 'snode *' from incompatible type 'sentry *'

Comment: I recommended that you should remove `sentry` and change the other structures. There are three structures: `stud`, `snode`, and `slist`, there are two functions, `readFile` and `main`

Comment: oh, my mistake. forgot to change it to snode. That fixed the problem. Thank you again Barmak.